# How to prevent programs from adding keyboard layout in Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows, keyboard-layout, language

My keyboard layouts are FR(France azerty) and AR(Morocco). My laptop keyboard is azerty so that's why I use French keyboard and the keymap is French because I'm North African.

The problem is that some programs, especially video games, add US English to the layouts list so when I want to switch from Arabic to French, for example, I have to switch twice from Arabic to English to French. I hate it a lot. There is a workaround where you have to add the english layout in region options and then remove it

What I want is a batch file or C(++) script to do it automatically by a period or command in RUN.